# org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: POSTGRESQL

Tags: spring, postgresql, jpa

Hi I am currently confused right now I have the following code:

Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/displayFile")
public List<Files> getFile(){
    return dbFileRepository.findAll();
}
```

Model:

```
@Entity
public class Files implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id    
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
private String fileId;

private String fileName;

private String fileType;yy

@Lob
private byte[] fileData;

//setters and getters
```

this code works fine when I'm using MYSQL but when I migrated my MYSQL DB into POSTGRESQL then it suddenly did not work I am confused as to why this particular endpoint did not work on a simple select * query statement while my other endpoint that has similar select * query works here is the full stack trace thank you in advance

```
"exception": "org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException",
"message": "could not execute query; SQL [select files0_.file_id as file_id1_2_, files0_.file_data as 
file_dat2_2_, files0_.file_name as file_nam3_2_, files0_.file_type as file_typ4_2_ from files 
files0_]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute query",
```

Comment: Could you please provide more information, like the full stack trace od the error showed on the console?

Comment: The full stack trace is already there